# Getting trouble accessing tumblr API using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, tumblr, http-status-code-400, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to post to tumblr using Google Apps Script. I have learnt Tumblr uses OAuth V1. To get an idea and to test the API I copied the [GSuiteDevs Apps Script OAuth1 Twitter Sample code available at Github](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth1/blob/master/samples/Twitter.gs).

I have suitably modified wherever necessary. After running the script, I am getting an error `400.8001` which according to [Tumblr API Documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts---createreblog-a-post-neue-post-format) is due to

> "when an NPF JSON parameter is invalid or a bad format".

The code and the error are provided below:

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXVQoZ0kLUYB7GDHzJZcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXlLVQS2z3WpXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

/**
 * Authorizes and makes a request to the Tumblr API.
 */
function run() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{MY BLOG IDENTIFIER COMES HERE}.tumblr.com/posts';
    var payload = {
      "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Hello world!"
        }
    ]
    };
    var response = service.fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      payload: payload
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.authorize();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  }
} 

/**
 * Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
 */
function reset() {
  var service = getService();
  service.reset();
}

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService() {
  return OAuth1.createService('Tumblr')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token')
      .setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token')
      .setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize')

      // Set the consumer key and secret.
      .setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
      .setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Using a cache will reduce the need to read from 
      // the property store and may increase performance.
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}

/**
 * Handles the OAuth callback.
 */
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied');
  }
}
```

The error is shown below:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.tumblr.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":[],"errors":[{"title":"Bad Request","code":8001,"detail":"Posting failed. Please try again."}]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 457, file "Service")

What is the problem in the code?

Comment: try `payload: JSON.stringify(payload)`

Comment: @TheMaster That gives error 401. ``` {
  "meta": {
    "status": 401,
    "msg": "Unauthorized"
  },
  "response": [],
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Unauthorized",
      "code": 1016,
      "detail": "Unable to authorize"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Run `reset()` and try authorizing again.   Make sure all your credentials/keys/secrets are right.

Comment: @TheMaster I did it again. Using JSON.stringify gives 401, and without it gives 400.

Comment: 400 is bad request. so json  should be stringified. 401 is unauthorized.  For whatever reason, your authorization credentials are not valid. make sure it isn't a issue with your service provider by testing with curl or postman.if not, try creating a issue in the oauth library github

Comment: One last thing: try setting `contentType:"application/json"` in `options` with and without `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @TheMaster It worked. :)

Comment: `contentType:"application/json"`  with `JSON.stringify` Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @TheMaster

The errors were in not including `contentType:"application/json"` and `JSON.stringify(payload)` . Those need to be included.